# Improve MySQL database design

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have 2 questions regarding how I should design my SQL(SQLite3) database. The way I use my database is like so:

I have an adjective(or any word really) & I need to resolve that word to its noun form. So for "happily" I need to resolve that word to "happy"(a noun & its generic form). For "hungrier" I need to resolve it to "hungry"

*Q1:* The majority of my SQL queries will involve myself searching the noun table for a specific word(row). **Which SQL table design would be best for my needs & more efficient in terms of speed of search/lookup?**

```
CREATE TABLE NounTable (u_id int PRIMARY KEY, u_word varchar, u_noun varchar);
// OR
CREATE TABLE NounTable (u_word varchar PRIMARY KEY, u_noun varchar);

// The majority of my queries will be searching according to the word column
SELECT u_noun FROM NounTable WHERE u_word="hungrier";
```

*Q2:* If I have a unique integer ID for each row, when I add a new row I need to find the a unique integer ID thats not already taken by another row. In my case each row will have an id in ascending order so for row1 the id=2, for row 2=2....row n=n.

In the past to add a row I first find the largest unique ID then add 1 to it then create that new row. But I once heard that there is an SQL variable, I think called **autonumber** that will do this automatically, is that true? Ie, it will automatically increment. So should I use that instead or would you recommend I stick with having the id as an integer?

```
CREATE TABLE NounTable (u_id int PRIMARY KEY, u_word varchar, u_noun varchar);
// Or shd I do this...
CREATE TABLE NounTable (u_id autonumber PRIMARY KEY, u_word varchar, u_noun varchar);
```

PS: is there much difference between MYSQL & SQLite if any? Maybe different variables? Or is the only difference in the way they store & look up information in the database?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance if you index u_word in your first alternative, there won't be much of a difference. It depends mostly on what other tables you have and whether you want to represent pairs of words or have a word and its noun.

If you don't have any particular reason to increment your IDs you should use autonumber. Increasing the key by one manually you always run the risk of a race condition and a collision while IIRC that is handled by autonumber.